# How to analyse row's with similar ID's in PySpark?

Tags: r, pyspark

I have a very large Dataset (160k rows).
I want to analyse each subset of rows with the same ID.
I only care about subsets with the same ID that are at least 30rows long.

What approach should I use?

I did the same task in R and did the following (from what it seems that can't be translated to pyspark):
Order by ascending order.
check whether next row is same as current, if yes n=n+1, if no i do my analysis and save the results. Rinse and Repeat for the whole lenght of the Data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy method is to group by 'ID' and collect the columns that are needed for your analysis.

1. If just one column:

   grouped_df = original_df.groupby('ID').agg(F.collect_list("column_m")).alias("for_analysis"))
2. If you need multiple columns, you can use struct:

   ```
   grouped_df = original_df.groupby('ID').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("column_m", "column_n", "column_o")).alias("for_analysis"))
   ```

Then, once you have your data per ID, you can use a UDF to perform your elaborate analysis

```
 grouped_df = grouped_df.withColumn('analysis_result', analyse_udf('for_analysis', ...))
```

Comment: how is that going to behave if have a unknown amount of groups?
What does this do exactly?: 
 
original_df.groupby('ID').agg(F.collect_list("column_m")).alias("for_analysis"))

Comment: i tried around using this approach and i think i can make it work; much appreciated ;)

Comment: yeah , for each ID in grouped_df, you can pass the 'for_analysis' data to a UDF and perform your analysis there and put the result in to a new column. I will update the answer